# Equivalent to Eclipse Classpath Container in Intellij IDEA

Tags: eclipse, plugins, intellij-idea, classpath, equivalent

I've written an Eclipse plug-in that provides a classpath container (just for the sake of completeness - the CPC gets its knowledge from the local development server). 
Now I was asked to provide the same functionallity for IntelliJ IDEA.

So does IntelliJ support a similar technology or how would someone implement dynamically computed classpath entries as an intelliJ plug-in.

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Udo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for ["Libraries" or "Global Libraries"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/library.html). The group jars and loose classes into collections that your modules can depend on.
Libraries are defined for a single project, whereas global libraries are available in every project in IDEA (hence "Global").

You can define both via the Project Settings screen (`CTRL`+`ALT`+`SHIFT`+`S`).